# Composer permission denied and sudo doesn't work

Tags: centos, composer-php

I'm on a CentOS server. When I call `composer install` I get the following error:

`bash: /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied`

`sudo composer install` gives me this:

`sudo: composer: command not found`

Really baffled here. Anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Edit: I've done some more research, and it seems that I'm not even downloading Composer in my directory. `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` doesn't actually do anything!

Comment: Can you `ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep composer`?

Comment: @ryekayo composer has perms of 644 and owner root:root

Comment: Im assuming you already used to curl to get it, according to the program's website. So Can you try this: Create an alias in your bashrc file: `alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer.phar'`

Comment: @ryekayo I'm getting a `-bash: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar: No such file or directory` error now. The /usr/local/bin file is `composer`, not `composer.phar`

Comment: @ryekayo and to answer your other question, I've tried `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` and nothing seems to happen...

Comment: Ok do you have any network connectivity?

Comment: @ryekayo yeah, I can curl google.com just fine :\

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer`

Answer (score 4):

First install the composer globally like mentioned in the [composer installation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) documentation. I just added here for reference.

```
 $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and then move the file to *'/usr/local/bin'.*

```
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Try to run `composer -V`. If you get a output like `Composer version` followed by the version number then the composer is installed successfully.

If you get any output like `composer: command not found` means use the following command to create a alias for the composer. So it will be executed globally.

```
$ alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'
```

Now if you run `composer -V` means you will get the output as `Composer Version` followed by the version number.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I still get ``$ sudo composer install; sudo: composer: command not found``. If I use ``composer install``, I get a permission denied when it attempts to create directories.

Comment: To comment on my previous comment: in the end, I just used the ``/vagrant`` directory instead of ``/srv/`` in the box.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```